# Eclipse Dynamic Web Project Error - The imports org.apache.axis2.om Cannot Be Resolved

Tags: eclipse, web-services, apache-axis

My Eclipse project underlines in red the imports below 'org.apache.axis2.om' with message...

'The imports org.apache.axis2.om Cannot Be Resolved'

import org.apache.axis2.om.OMAbstractFactory;

import org.apache.axis2.om.OMElement;

import org.apache.axis2.om.OMFactory;

import org.apache.axis2.om.OMNamespace;

What is the cause and how can I fix it in Eclipse..?

Regards,

Comment: The intelli sense in Eclipse reconginses up to 'org.apache.axis2' it seems 'OM' is missing...

Comment: I had to download the JAR 'axis2-0.9.jar' from Maven Repository' and then add it to my project after which the application compiled without errors...

Comment: I think your Axis2 configurations of Eclipse may be incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add axis2-kernal jar to your project. This can be done by right clicking your project then click build path -> configure build path -> libraries - add external jars, then you can add this jar from your system to your project.